# mysql remove the starting \r\n only in the beginning of text fields?

Tags: mysql, regex

because of a poorly coded filter on textarea fields i have in mmy db plenty of varchar fields (but not all of them..) starting with new lines and/or returns "\r \n" before the text, texts which also contains linebreaks..

an example can be seen here : http://paraglidingearth.com/?site=14301

i wish i could remove only the "\r\n" that are at the beginning of the fields and not those inside the text, without altering of course the text itself...

i guess this requires some fancy regex in an UPDATE mysql query but i ask for help here as i can't write this piece of filter by myself...

thanks for help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trim is the function of choice if all you are trying to do is trim leading '\n' and '\r\n' from your strings....

```
set @string:='\r\nHello World';

select @string;
+---------------+
| @string       |
+---------------+
|
Hello World |
+---------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)


select trim(leading '\n' from trim(leading '\r\n' from @string));
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| trim(leading '\n' from trim(leading '\r\n' from @string)) |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| Hello World                                               |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)



set @string:='\nHello World';

select trim(leading '\n' from trim(leading '\r\n' from @string));
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| trim(leading '\n' from trim(leading '\r\n' from @string)) |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| Hello World                                               |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

The following example shows that newlines embedded within the string are ignored...

```
set @string:='Hello\n World';
select trim(leading '\n' from trim(leading '\r\n' from @string));
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| trim(leading '\n' from trim(leading '\r\n' from @string)) |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| Hello
World                                              |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: definitely the function I was missing !!! :)   
it did the job just fine !   THanks !!

Answer (score 0):

They don't `\r\n` or `\n,` they are `<br>` tag. I inspected your site and it seems like `<br>` tag

With only mysql you should use

Mysql `REPLACE()` and `TRIM()` while updating your fields. 
**But these are dangerous operations for your data. First backup your database** then work with `REPLACE()`, `TRIM()` and `UPDATE`

Comment: hi, "br" tags in html file are due to nl2br function used for displaying content on page, sorry i forgot to mention that in the question..